# How to add grand totals excl in magento 2 checkout cart

Tags: magento2

I want to add grand totals exc in Magento 2 checkout cart. Like cart summary in checkout payment step.

Checkout payment step.

[image]

Checkout cart.

[image]

UPDATE IMAGE

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the system configurations?

Comment: Yes, I checked it