# Magento 2: Change order totals block sort order in order emails only

Tags: magento2, email

I want to add some changes in Magento 2 email order_totals.

[image]

I searched and found it

```
<tfoot class="order-totals">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
</tfoot>
```

Where do I change it? Please help me

Comment: Do you want to change it in order emails right?

Comment: Hi sumit, yes i do

Answer (score 3):

You can change the sort order of the totals by following the below path in the Magento admin.

```
Stores > Configurations > Sales > Sales > Checkout Totals Sort Order
```

If you want to change it only for the emails then you need to change the layout handle `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}` described in the email template which contains `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml` file.

In this file, the total block is defined `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml`. You can override it as per your requirements.

**Ex. override theme:**

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Sales/templates/order/totals.phtml
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: I tried, but it also changed the frontend, I just wanted to change it in the email

Comment: This is because of all of the totals block is coming from the same file "/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml".

Comment: I found and known that it is so, is there any way we can customize it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an idea to override the totals block only for the order emails.

Comment: I came across the totals.phtml file and unfortunately, I don't know how to change it as expected: ((((

Comment: Yes, this file will be getting the order totals block as per given sort order in the admin.

Comment: Can you help me with another problem? it's https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289791/how-to-add-grand-totals-excl-in-magento-2-checkout-cart

Comment: Sure, I might have to ask you to help with this matter again

Comment: Its worked for me

Comment: Excellent answer!